# Nested list with mutiple levels to data.frame in R

Tags: r, json, list, dictionary, nested

From an API, I get a complex and large list that is deeply nested, and with an ueven number of elements.

I use map to get the data I want, but I want to convert the resulting list to a data frame, see code below. Any pointers?

```
# Example structure
list <- list(
  Player1 = c("D" = "2020-05-13",
              "T" = "Test 1",
            c("Common" = list(c("X" = 300,
                         "Y" = 345,
                         "Z" = 500)))),
  Player2 = c("D" = "2020-05-13",
            "T" = "Test 2",
            c("Common" = list(c("X" = 320,
                                "Y" = 365,
                                "Z" = 300)))))

# Desired output 
df <- data.frame(
  player = c("Player1", "Player 2"),
  D = c("2020-05-13", "2020-05-13"),
  T = c("Test 1", "Test 2"),
  X = c(300, 320),
  Y = c(345, 365),
  Z = c(500, 300))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly convert api response to dataframe by using something like this. Can you try.

```
response <- POST(url,body  = arg, encode = "json")
cwr_json <- fromJSON(httr::content(response, "text"), flatten = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(cwr_json)
```

Answer (score 1):

A method using the `purrr` package.

```
library(purrr)

map_dfr(list1, as.data.frame, .id = 'player')
```

Answer (score 1):

in Base-R

```
as.data.frame(t(sapply(list,unlist)))

                 D      T Common.X Common.Y Common.Z
Player1 2020-05-13 Test 1      300      345      500
Player2 2020-05-13 Test 2      320      365      300
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `unnest_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
tibble(col1 = list, player = names(col1)) %>% 
     unnest_wider(c(col1)) %>%
     unnest_wider(c(Common))
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#  D          T          X     Y     Z player 
#  <chr>      <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
#1 2020-05-13 Test 1   300   345   500 Player1
#2 2020-05-13 Test 2   320   365   300 Player2
```